# How to display 5 questions from a JavaScript array at the same time in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am developing a page for a quiz or a test with lots of questions and in my HTML its only showing one question at a time from the questions array I have created, but I need to show 5 questions at a time, and when next button is clicked it needs to show the next set of 5 questions. How can I do this, please help.

```js
let questions = [{
      numb: 1,
      question: "What does HTML stand for?",
      answer: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
      options: [
        "Hyper Text Preprocessor",
        "Hyper Text Markup Language",
        "Hyper Text Multiple Language",
        "Hyper Tool Multi Language"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 2,
      question: "What does CSS stand for?",
      answer: "Cascading Style Sheet",
      options: [
        "Common Style Sheet",
        "Colorful Style Sheet",
        "Computer Style Sheet",
        "Cascading Style Sheet"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 3,
      question: "What does PHP stand for?",
      answer: "Hypertext Preprocessor",
      options: [
        "Hypertext Preprocessor",
        "Hypertext Programming",
        "Hypertext Preprogramming",
        "Hometext Preprocessor"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 4,
      question: "What does SQL stand for?",
      answer: "Structured Query Language",
      options: [
        "Stylish Question Language",
        "Stylesheet Query Language",
        "Statement Question Language",
        "Structured Query Language"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 5,
      question: "What does XML stand for?",
      answer: "eXtensible Markup Language",
      options: [
        "eXtensible Markup Language",
        "eXecutable Multiple Language",
        "eXTra Multi-Program Language",
        "eXamine Multiple Language"
      ]
    }]
    //for questions
    //selecting all required elements
    const start_btn = document.querySelector(".start_btn button");
    const info_box = document.querySelector(".info_box");
    const exit_btn = info_box.querySelector(".buttons .quit");
    const continue_btn = info_box.querySelector(".buttons .restart");
    const quiz_box = document.querySelector(".quiz_box");
    const result_box = document.querySelector(".result_box");
    const option_list = document.querySelector(".option_list");
    const time_line = document.querySelector("header .time_line");
    const timeText = document.querySelector(".timer .time_left_txt");
    const timeCount = document.querySelector(".timer .timer_sec");

    // if startQuiz button clicked
    start_btn.onclick = () => {
      // info_box.classList.add("activeInfo"); //show info box
      info_box.classList.remove("activeInfo"); //hide info box
      quiz_box.classList.add("activeQuiz"); //show quiz box
      showQuetions(0); //calling showQestions function
      queCounter(1); //passing 1 parameter to queCounter
      startTimer(120); //calling startTimer function
      startTimerLine(0); //calling startTimerLine function
    }



    let timeValue = 15;
    let que_count = 0;
    let que_numb = 1;
    let userScore = 0;
    let counter;
    let counterLine;
    let widthValue = 0;

    const restart_quiz = result_box.querySelector(".buttons .restart");
    const quit_quiz = result_box.querySelector(".buttons .quit");

    // if restartQuiz button clicked
    restart_quiz.onclick = () => {
      quiz_box.classList.add("activeQuiz"); //show quiz box
      result_box.classList.remove("activeResult"); //hide result box
      timeValue = 15;
      que_count = 0;
      que_numb = 1;
      userScore = 0;
      widthValue = 0;
      showQuetions(que_count); //calling showQestions function
      queCounter(que_numb); //passing que_numb value to queCounter
      clearInterval(counter); //clear counter
      clearInterval(counterLine); //clear counterLine
      startTimer(timeValue); //calling startTimer function
      startTimerLine(widthValue); //calling startTimerLine function
      timeText.textContent = "Time Left"; //change the text of timeText to Time Left
      next_btn.classList.remove("show"); //hide the next button
    }

    // if quitQuiz button clicked
    quit_quiz.onclick = () => {
      window.location.reload(); //reload the current window
    }

    const next_btn = document.querySelector("footer .next_btn");
    const bottom_ques_counter = document.querySelector("footer .total_que");

    // if Next Que button clicked
    next_btn.onclick = () => {
      if (que_count < questions.length - 1) { //if question count is less than total question length
        que_count++; //increment the que_count value
        que_numb++; //increment the que_numb value
        showQuetions(que_count); //calling showQestions function
        queCounter(que_numb); //passing que_numb value to queCounter
        clearInterval(counter); //clear counter
        clearInterval(counterLine); //clear counterLine
        startTimer(timeValue); //calling startTimer function
        startTimerLine(widthValue); //calling startTimerLine function
        timeText.textContent = "Time Left"; //change the timeText to Time Left
        next_btn.classList.remove("show"); //hide the next button
      } else {
        clearInterval(counter); //clear counter
        clearInterval(counterLine); //clear counterLine
        showResult(); //calling showResult function
      }
    }

    // getting questions and options from array
    function showQuetions(index) {
      const que_text = document.querySelector(".que_text");

      //creating a new span and div tag for question and option and passing the value using array index
      let que_tag = '<span>' + questions[index].numb + ". " + questions[index].question + '</span>';
      let option_tag = '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[0] + '</span></div>' +
        '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[1] + '</span></div>' +
        '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[2] + '</span></div>' +
        '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[3] + '</span></div>';

      que_text.innerHTML = que_tag; //adding new span tag inside que_tag
      option_list.innerHTML = option_tag; //adding new div tag inside option_tag

      const option = option_list.querySelectorAll(".option");

      // set onclick attribute to all available options
      for (i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
        option[i].setAttribute("onclick", "optionSelected(this)");
      }

    }
    // creating the new div tags which for icons


    let tickIconTag = '<div class="icon tick"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div>';
    let crossIconTag = '<div class="icon cross"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>';

    //if user clicked on option
    function optionSelected(answer) {
      clearInterval(counter); //clear counter
      clearInterval(counterLine); //clear counterLine
      let userAns = answer.textContent; //getting user selected option
      let correcAns = questions[que_count].answer; //getting correct answer from array
      const allOptions = option_list.children.length; //getting all option items

      if (userAns == correcAns) { //if user selected option is equal to array's correct answer
        userScore += 1; //upgrading score value with 1
        answer.classList.add("correct"); //adding green color to correct selected option
        answer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tickIconTag); //adding tick icon to correct selected option
        console.log("Correct Answer");
        console.log("Your correct answers = " + userScore);
      } else {
        answer.classList.add("incorrect"); //adding red color to correct selected option
        answer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", crossIconTag); //adding cross icon to correct selected option
        console.log("Wrong Answer");

        for (i = 0; i < allOptions; i++) {
          if (option_list.children[i].textContent == correcAns) { //if there is an option which is matched to an array answer 
            option_list.children[i].setAttribute("class", "option correct"); //adding green color to matched option
            option_list.children[i].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tickIconTag); //adding tick icon to matched option
            console.log("Auto selected correct answer.");
          }
        }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < allOptions; i++) {
        option_list.children[i].classList.add("disabled"); //once user select an option then disabled all options
      }
      next_btn.classList.add("show"); //show the next button if user selected any option
    }

    function showResult() {
      info_box.classList.remove("activeInfo"); //hide info box
      quiz_box.classList.remove("activeQuiz"); //hide quiz box
      result_box.classList.add("activeResult"); //show result box
      const scoreText = result_box.querySelector(".score_text");
      if (userScore > 3) { // if user scored more than 3
        //creating a new span tag and passing the user score number and total question number
        let scoreTag = '<span>and congrats! , You got <p>' + userScore + '</p> out of <p>' + questions.length + '</p></span>';
        scoreText.innerHTML = scoreTag; //adding new span tag inside score_Text
      } else if (userScore > 1) { // if user scored more than 1
        let scoreTag = '<span>and nice , You got <p>' + userScore + '</p> out of <p>' + questions.length + '</p></span>';
        scoreText.innerHTML = scoreTag;
      } else { // if user scored less than 1
        let scoreTag = '<span>and sorry , You got only <p>' + userScore + '</p> out of <p>' + questions.length + '</p></span>';
        scoreText.innerHTML = scoreTag;
      }
    }

    function startTimer(time) {
      counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

      function timer() {
        timeCount.textContent = time; //changing the value of timeCount with time value
        time--; //decrement the time value
        if (time < 9) { //if timer is less than 9
          let addZero = timeCount.textContent;
          timeCount.textContent = "0" + addZero; //add a 0 before time value
        }
        if (time < 0) { //if timer is less than 0
          clearInterval(counter); //clear counter
          timeText.textContent = "Time Off"; //change the time text to time off
          const allOptions = option_list.children.length; //getting all option items
          let correcAns = questions[que_count].answer; //getting correct answer from array
          for (i = 0; i < allOptions; i++) {
            if (option_list.children[i].textContent == correcAns) { //if there is an option which is matched to an array answer
              option_list.children[i].setAttribute("class", "option correct"); //adding green color to matched option
              option_list.children[i].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tickIconTag); //adding tick icon to matched option
              console.log("Time Off: Auto selected correct answer.");
            }
          }
          for (i = 0; i < allOptions; i++) {
            option_list.children[i].classList.add("disabled"); //once user select an option then disabled all options
          }
          next_btn.classList.add("show"); //show the next button if user selected any option
        }
      }
    }

    function startTimerLine(time) {
      counterLine = setInterval(timer, 29);

      function timer() {
        time += 1; //upgrading time value with 1
        time_line.style.width = time + "px"; //increasing width of time_line with px by time value
        if (time > 549) { //if time value is greater than 549
          clearInterval(counterLine); //clear counterLine
        }
      }
    }

    function queCounter(index) {
      //creating a new span tag and passing the question number and total question
      let totalQueCounTag = '<span><p>' + index + '</p> of <p>' + questions.length + '</p> Questions</span>';
      bottom_ques_counter.innerHTML = totalQueCounTag; //adding new span tag inside bottom_ques_counter
    }
```

```html
<!-- questions -->
<div class="start_btn"><button>Start Answering</button></div>

<!-- Info Box -->
<div class="info_box">

  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="quit">Exit Quiz</button>
    <button class="restart">Continue</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Quiz Box -->
<div class="quiz_box">
  <header>
    <div class="title">Questions</div>
    <div class="timer">
      <div class="time_left_txt">Time Left</div>
      <div class="timer_sec">15</div>
    </div>
    <div class="time_line"></div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="que_text">
    </div>
    <div class="option_list">
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- footer of Quiz Box -->
  <footer>
    <div class="total_que">
      <!-- Here I've inserted Question Count Number from JavaScript -->
    </div>
    <button class="next_btn">Next Que</button>
  </footer>
</div>

<!-- Result Box -->
<div class="result_box">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-crown"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="complete_text">You've completed the Quiz!</div>
  <div class="score_text">
    <!-- Here I've inserted Score Result from JavaScript -->
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="restart">Replay Quiz</button>
    <button class="quit">Quit Quiz</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Loop. 2. Please delegate. If you wrote the code, why can't you change it to loop in showQuestions?

Comment: he cant though.. his whole system is build around the concept of 1 question at a time.. i tried looping, and if it was slightly dynamic functions, it would work but even after i loop, nothing happens

Comment: yea.. im slow, but I FINALLY DID IT(rebuilt the questionaire thing) im gonna bookmark :D

Comment: I am newbie in this field, so I don't know much about JavaScript. So can you help me with this.

Comment: jn, i realise that my counting isn't working :{ brb

Comment: Can you show me how , please.

Comment: Can you please sent me the code. It will be very helpful for me. It's a bit urgent

Comment: sry for the wait.. i tried explaining the best I could

Comment: btw @Asif it was fun and all but i worked pretty hard on this.. could you mark it pls?

Comment: @Asif, u there? I answered your question.. if it works, can you mark please? Just saying u wouldn't like something like this happening to u the other way around :{

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Here is a [repl](https://repl.it/join/crutazpo-paultaylor2) which shows what you wanted with `Next` and `Previous` buttons

Too much was built so rigid around that entire construct.. so editing your code was hard.. instead I just made a dynamic question display setup(`n` controls the amount of questions displayed because `displayQuestion` displays all questions that is given with the `arr` argument)

Now for the step by step walkthrough

There are **3** main functions:

1. **The event listener of `startBtn`**: the first line inside this code simply changes the text displayed from the `startButton`, not all that important.. right below that is an important variable `n` which is used in a filter later down in such a way that n **CONTROLS** the amount of questions that will be displayed at one time
2. **The `displayQuestions` function**: this function takes in 2 arguments; `arr` and `questionBar`. `arr` is the array of questions given(remember it's the event listener that gives an intelligently filtered array of questions). it iterates through each question item, makes an `element`(which would encompass the question and its options), a `function`(which would be **click** `listeners` for all the different `options` of the `question`; and stop listening from all options when one is selected) and then it iterates through the `options` to `append` the options to the parent `question` and add the specialised `listener function` to each `option`
3. **The `displayResults` function**: this takes in the results object(in its first argument) and prints the main results to given element(in its second argument)

```js
var questionBar=document.getElementById('questions')

var startBtn=document.getElementById('start')
startBtn.addEventListener('click', async function(){
  questionBar.innerHTML="" //important to prevent overlap(move this line to the beginning of the displayQuestions to ONLY show 5 questions at a time on the whole document)
  startBtn.innerText="Restart Questions"
  var n=5 //change this number to change the amount of questions shown
  var results={correct:0,totalPossible:0}
  for(var i=0;i<questions.length;i+=n){
    var result=await displayQuestions(
      questions.filter((a,j)=>j>=i&&j<i+n),
      questionBar
    )
    Object.keys(result).forEach(a=>{
      if(a=="correct"){results.correct+=result.correct}
      else if(a=="totalPossible"){results.totalPossible+=result.totalPossible}
      else{results[a]=result[a]}
    })
  }
  displayResults(results,questionBar)
})

async function displayQuestions(arr,questionBar){
  var finished=arr.length //a test for if all questions answered
  var answered=0; var correct=0
  var corrections={}
  arr.forEach(a=>{
    var question=document.createElement('div')
    question.className="question" //for css to change looks
    
    var options=[] //will become an array of elements(that have the question options) in order to remove event listener from them
    //the function below handles when a question option is selected and removes listening when an answer is selected(one can only answer once)
    function listen(ev){
      var answer=ev.path[0].innerText
      if(answer==a.answer){
        question.className="correct";correct++;answered++
        ev.path[0].className="selected"
        corrections[a.numb]={
          correct:true, userAnswer:answer, correctAnswer:a.answer
        }
      }
      else{
        question.className="wrong";answered++
        ev.path[0].className="selected"
        corrections[a.numb]={
          correct:false, userAnswer:answer, correctAnswer:a.answer
        }
      }
      options.forEach(c=>{c.removeEventListener('click',listen)})
    }
   
    var title=document.createElement('span')
    title.classList.add('title') //for css to change looks
    title.innerText=`(${a.numb}) ${a.question}`
    question.appendChild(title)
    
    a.options.forEach(b=>{
      var option=document.createElement('div')
      option.className="option" //for css to change looks
      option.innerText=b
      option.addEventListener('click',listen)
      options.push(option)
      question.appendChild(option)
    })
    questionBar.appendChild(question)
  })
  var p=new Promise(results=>{
    var i=setInterval(()=>{
      if(answered==finished){
        clearInterval(i) //the timeout INSIDE the interval ensures that I can fix the time that you have to look at the final display of what was right and wrong before the results function is run
        //it's just a personal preference because it looks glitchy when the question immediately goes into results
        setTimeout(()=>{
          corrections.correct=correct
          corrections.totalPossible=finished
          results(corrections)
        },1000)
      }
    },0)
  })
  return await p
}

function displayResults(corrections,elem){
  //the corrections object has A LOT of data you can use in MANY ways
  console.log(corrections)
  var correct=corrections.correct
  var totalPossible=corrections.totalPossible
  elem.innerText=`You got ${correct} of ${totalPossible}`
}
```

```css
.wrong {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.correct {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.question{
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.title{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.option{
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  margin: 5px;
}
.selected{
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="start_btn">
  <button id="start">Start Questions</button>
</div>
<div id="questions"></div>

<script>
//btw all numb values should be unique.. I'm counting on that xD
let questions = [{
      numb: 1,
      question: "What does HTML stand for?",
      answer: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
      options: [
        "Hyper Text Preprocessor",
        "Hyper Text Markup Language",
        "Hyper Text Multiple Language",
        "Hyper Tool Multi Language"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 2,
      question: "What does CSS stand for?",
      answer: "Cascading Style Sheet",
      options: [
        "Common Style Sheet",
        "Colorful Style Sheet",
        "Computer Style Sheet",
        "Cascading Style Sheet"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 3,
      question: "What does PHP stand for?",
      answer: "Hypertext Preprocessor",
      options: [
        "Hypertext Preprocessor",
        "Hypertext Programming",
        "Hypertext Preprogramming",
        "Hometext Preprocessor"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 4,
      question: "What does SQL stand for?",
      answer: "Structured Query Language",
      options: [
        "Stylish Question Language",
        "Stylesheet Query Language",
        "Statement Question Language",
        "Structured Query Language"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 5,
      question: "What does XML stand for?",
      answer: "eXtensible Markup Language",
      options: [
        "eXtensible Markup Language",
        "eXecutable Multiple Language",
        "eXTra Multi-Program Language",
        "eXamine Multiple Language"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 6,
      question: "Why did the cow cross the road",
      answer: "There was no road, it was grass",
      options: [
        "idk LOL",
        "COWS CAN'T SWIM",
        "There was no road, it was grass",
        "Bruh pls, NEXT"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 7,
      question: "How to select element with 2 classes(CSS)",
      answer: "Chain dots like: .a.b",
      options: [
        "Chain dots like: .a.b",
        "It's impossible",
        "Sequence dots like: .a .b",
        "explore the universe, then come back"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 8,
      question: "What is 9+10?",
      answer: "Nineteen",
      options: [
        "Twenty one",
        "nothing at all, irrelevant",
        "IDK, YOU TELL ME",
        "Nineteen"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 9,
      question: "How does a C linked list work?",
      answer: "structs and pointer logic",
      options: [
        "high level javascript magic",
        "some random module",
        "that doesn't exist",
        "structs and pointer logic"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 10,
      question: "Is light a particle?",
      answer: "It behaves like a particle AND a wave",
      options: [
        "Affirmitave",
        "Nope, not even close",
        "It behaves like a particle AND a wave",
        "It's a unicorn"
      ]
    },
    {
      numb: 11,
      question: "What is a bit?",
      answer: "A binary digit",
      options: [
        "A binary digit",
        "BEEP BOOP",
        "69",
        "idk smh xD"
      ]
    }
]
</script>
```

Comment: one more thing , after the 1st 5 questions are displayed its automatically showing the next set of questions, instead of this can i include a next button at the bottom, so that only when i click the next button the rest of questions will display.

Comment: oh just take off the line that says `questionBar.innerHTML=""` in function `displayQuestions` and move it right under the `startBtn.addEventListener` line

Comment: i just edited the answer(did what i described above)

Comment: sorry , but this is not what i meant. i want to add next and previous button in this , so that when i click the next button it shows the next set of 5 questions from the array in the next page, same for the previous button too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228187/discussion-between-asif-and-the-bomb-squad).